# pyspark: rolling average using Custom timeseries data

Tags: apache-spark, pyspark, spark-streaming, apache-spark-sql

Hi My base data frame is looks like this .

```
'|stockId|timeStamp|stockPrice|'
+-------+---------+----------+
|    101|        1|      53.0|
|    101|        2|      15.0|
|    101|        3|      57.0|
|    101|        4|      71.0|
|    101|        5|      86.0|
```

This is my code which converts days.followed by window and average window .

```
days=lambda i:i*86400
W=Window.partitionBy(F.col('stockId')).orderBy(F.col('epoch_time').cast("timestamp").cast("long")).rangeBetween(-days(3),0)
Df=.withColumn("current_timestamp",F.unix_timestamp(F.lit(timestamp),'yyyy-MM-dd HH:mm:ss').cast("timestamp"))\
.withColumn("epoch",F.unix_timestamp("current_timestamp"))\
.withColumn("epoch_time",F.concat(F.col("epoch")+F.col("timeStamp")))\
.withColumn("moving_avg",F.avg("stockPrice").over(W))
```

This is my result.

```
+-------+---------+----------+-------------------+----------+----------+-----------------+
|stockId|timeStamp|stockPrice|  current_timestamp|     epoch|epoch_time|       moving_avg|
+-------+---------+----------+-------------------+----------+----------+-----------------+
|    101|        1|      53.0|2020-01-21 10:53:43|1579584223|1579584224|48.21782178217822|
|    101|        2|      15.0|2020-01-21 10:53:43|1579584223|1579584225|48.21782178217822|
|    101|        3|      57.0|2020-01-21 10:53:43|1579584223|1579584226|48.21782178217822|
|    101|        4|      86.0|2020-01-21 10:53:43|1579584223|1579584227|48.21782178217822|
```

Expected output

```
+-------+---------+----------+-------------------+----------+----------+-----------------+
|stockId|timeStamp|stockPrice|  current_timestamp|     epoch|epoch_time|       moving_avg|
+-------+---------+----------+-------------------+----------+----------+-----------------+
|    101|        3|      57.0|2020-01-21 10:53:43|1579584223|1579584226|41.67|
|    101|        4|      71.0|2020-01-21 10:53:43|1579584223|1579584227|47.67|
|    101|        5|      71.0|2020-01-21 10:53:43|1579584223|1579584227|71.33|
```

Comment: what is i in days ?

Comment: its a lambda function which converts into seconds 24*60*60

Comment: thank you and on what basis you do not need first two rows?

Comment: For better understanding I have kept like this . But the rolling window is over 3 days .

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
W=Window.partitionBy(F.col('stockId')).orderBy(F.col('epoch_time').cast("timestamp").cast("long")).rangeBetween(-2,0)

+-------+---------+----------+-------------------+----------+----------+------
|stockId|timeStamp|stockPrice|  current_timestamp|     epoch|epoch_time|       moving_avg|
+-------+---------+----------+-------------------+----------+----------+-----------------+
|    101|        3|      57.0|2020-01-21 10:53:43|1579584223|1579584226|41.67|
|    101|        4|      71.0|2020-01-21 10:53:43|1579584223|1579584227|47.67|
|    101|        5|      71.0|2020-01-21 10:53:43|1579584223|1579584227|71.33|
```

After keeping the rolling`window rangeBetween(-2,0)` 
where the average went from `current row` to `3rd row of the table`.